# Javascript multi-dimensional array pass location

Tags: javascript, algorithm, multidimensional-array, nodes, a-star

I'm implementing a version of the A* path-finding algorithm in Javascript. To preserve my sanity, I'm using a pseudo-multi-dimensional array (i.e. nested arrays). If you aren't familiar with A*, one step is checking the surrounding nodes of an "open" node.

How can I pass the location of the "open" node and check adjacent nodes in my array? Shouldn't  array locations be first-class?

```
function checknode (node) //Such as [5,2]
{
     if(array[node+1][node]==something) //In this case [6,2]

}
```

Yeah, I know I could pass the x and y coordinates as seperate arguments, like so:

```
function checknode (nodex, nodey)
{
     if(array[nodex+1][nodey]==something)
}
```

But the implications this has as far as my code is concerned is undesirable.

**EDIT:** Basically, I'm wondering if the location of an item of an array (5,2) can be passed into my function and manipulated.

Comment: if `node = [5,2]` then `array[node+1]` is `array[ [5,2] + 1 ]` which makes no sense. Are you sure you don't mean `array[node[0]+1]`

Comment: That's what I meant. :) Sorry, I was having trouble communicating my intentions.

Comment: Are the arrays of identical length? Then why not nodex + nodey*LENGTH ?

Comment: The array is multidimensional. Nodex + nodey*length is a possibility (and I do, in fact, use it), but essentially my question was whether array item location is first-class data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a composite value (using an object) that contains the two coordinates. That way you can pass it as a single parameter:

```
function checknode(node) {
  if (array[node.x + 1][node.y] == something) //In this case [6,2]
}
```

Example call:

```
checknode({ x: 5, y: 2 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure what you exactly want but looks like you are passing in an array. Do you want something like

```
function checknode (node) //Such as [5,2]
{
     if( array[ node[0]+1 ][node[1]]==something) //In this case [6,2]

}
```

So if node s an array i.e. node = [5,2]
This code will check array[6][2] with "something"

Comment: I know I wasn't very clear. I was looking to see if Javascript somehow support passing the actual location of a point, so the parameter "node" would actually be a coordinate, [5][2].

Comment: No, you cannot do that. If the things you are comparing are objects (arrays etc.) and not primitives (strings/numbers) then the only way you are going to get === to return true is if both are a reference to the SAME object

Comment: so var a = [5,2] (could be a more complex object too or a multi D array)
var b = [,2] 
a === b will NOT return true.
However if you write var a = [5,2]
var b = a. Only then === will return true. They literally have to be the reference to the same object.

Comment: What course of action do you recommend I take, seeing as I can't compare two objects with the same contents? It would really be annoying to rewrite the whole framework for a one-dimensional array.